# Html Checkbox with entry

Tags: html, css

HTML code

```
<div class="text_site">
    <legend><h3>O:</h3></legend>
    <ul class = "no-bullets">
        <li> <input type="radio" name="radio-button" id="All" value="1"> <label class="radio-label">All</label> </li>
        <li> <input type="radio" name="radio-button" id="Just" value="0"> <label class="radio-label">Just</label></li>
        <ul class = "no-bullets">
            <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="H" name="o[]" value="H">
            <label for="H">H</label></li>
            <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="R" name="o[]" value="R">
            <label for="R">R</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</div>
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
<input type="reset" value="Clear the form"/>
```

CSS code

```
.no-bullets {
  list-style:none;
}
```

But i want to create a extra checkbox field, inside the `<li> </li>` tags where the user can write some text and this text need to be save in the "o[]" How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

That cannot be done. You should be able to a add a textarea however and simply assign it an id that is relevant to the checkbox. But if what you want is an optional, dynamically appearing textarea if a radio become checked you would need to use some javascript onclick action.

Comment: I don't know javascript how can i do that? can i leave the html like this?

Comment: @1pa A simple way would be to simply have some inline script in the html that adds a text area if the checkbox is checked. Lot's of similar examples and demonstration can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_onclick.asp).

Answer (score 0):

An Input field and a Checkbox are different input types.  They cannot be combined.  You can add an input field like this:

```
<li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="R" name="o[]" value="R">
        <label for="R">R</label>
        <input type="text" name="some_name" />
</li>
```

Comment: That's the layout i want! But the input doesn't go to the variable o[].. why?